# How can I use Promise.all on an array of objects and then reassign them to the relevant key in a new object?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm a bit stuck on the middle portion of my code. I know what I want the end to look like, and the beginning, but cannot seem to fill in the blank.

I call `fetch` on 4 API endpoints, and store the `Promises` into a relevant key that tells me what they are.

Then I loop through all of those using a `for in` loop, and push all those `Promises` into an array so I can call `Promise.all` on them.

After successfully logging the array to the console, I see now that the array is filled with objects with my data. **However, there is no way for me to tell which data belongs to what object key, like in the original object**.

Is there a better way to do this? **I do know for a fact that I want to use `Promise.all` here** in this code; that's something I don't want to budge on, because I am trying to figure out how I can make this possible without giving up (been at this for a couple hours now).

At the end of my code (this is just pseudocode for a real life example in my React app), I just want to take the final object, and push it into `state`.

Any help is appreciated.

```js
//imitating React State as an example
const state = {
  iliakan: '',
  remy: '',
  jeresig: '',
}

//put all of the urls in an object with a key-pair value to describe the data
const githubAPI = {
  iliakan: 'https://api.github.com/users/iliakan',
  remy: 'https://api.github.com/users/remy',
  jeresig: 'https://api.github.com/users/jeresig'
}

//create an empty object to assign promises to keys
const movieData = {};
const promiseArr = [];
//store promise into relevant key
for (const user in githubAPI) {
  movieData[user] = fetch().then(res => res.json())
}
//now movieData has keys with values set to related Promises
console.log(movieData);
//loop through these promises, and put them in an Array for Promise.all
for (const userData in movieData) {
  promiseArr.push(movieData[userData])
}

//Use Promise.all on all of those promises
Promise.all(promiseArr).then(responseArr => console.log(responseArr);

//this is where I am stuck. I now have an array of objects with all the correct data, but I don't know how to reassign them back to their original, matching key that they had in the movieData object!


//end goal is to have an object like this
//const movieData = {
//  iliakan: {//object with data from api},
//  remy: {//object with data from api},
//  jeresig: {//object with data from api}
//}

//use the movieData to setState and update current component state
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A way to do this, is by seeing the "connection between a key and a property" as it's own "thing" in programming: a key-value pair.
The javascript API calls them "entries", and uses a simple 2 element array as the "thing": `['key', 'value']` would be `key: 'value'`.

You can go from an object to entries with `Object.entries(the_object)`.
It will return an array with "entry-array"-s inside it:

```
const githubAPI = {
  iliakan: 'https://api.github.com/users/iliakan',
  remy: 'https://api.github.com/users/remy',
  jeresig: 'https://api.github.com/users/jeresig'
}

let githubEntries = Object.entries(githubAPI)
// githubEntries = [
//   ['iliakan', 'https://api.github.com/users/iliakan'],
//   ['remy', 'https://api.github.com/users/remy'],
//   ['jeresig', 'https://api.github.com/users/jeresig'],
// ]
```

Now you can use this concept, and make the promises also "entries", the result and the key combined in a `[key, value]` array. This way, you can later rebuild the object from the entries in the `Promise.all` result.

```
let promiseOfEntries = Promise.all(Object.entries(githubAPI).map((entry) => {
  let [key, value] = entry;
  return fetch().then(x => x.json()).then(result => {
    // Important step here: We combine the result with the key,
    // into a new [key, value] entry
    return [key, result];
  })
}

let promiseOfResults = promiseOfEntries.then(resultEntries => {
  // From the "entries", we build an object again here
  let results = {};
  for (let [key, value] of resultEntries) {
    results[key] = value;
  }
  return results;
});

promiseOfResults.then(results => {
  // Do anything with results!
  console.log('results:', results);
});
```

Lodash even has `_.fromPairs` to do this `[ [key, value], [key2, value2], ...]` to `{ key: value, key2: value2 }` conversion.
https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#fromPairs

You can use this concept of "entries" for any place where you juggle between objects and arrays.

Hope I explained it well enough, don't be afraid to ask questions in the comments if I haven't!

Comment: I actually do have a question (still going over the code you wrote line-by-line); on this line `return fetch().then(x => x.json()).then(result => {`, I should be filling in the `fetch()` like `fetch(value)`, correct?

Comment: @PhillipChoi yes! You can fill in any fetch arguments there, as you as you keep the `return [key, result];` to keep the result and the key connected

Comment: Such a creative approach that would've never crossed my mine. Thank you Michiel!

Answer (score 3):

You simply need to map the keys with the matching array indices. This is all you're missing:

```
const orderOfKeys = [] // create a helper Array

for (const userData in movieData) {
  promiseArr.push(movieData[userData])
  orderOfKeys.push(userData) // Memoize the keys, now the index matches the proper key
}

//Use Promise.all on all of those promises
Promise.all(promiseArr).then(responseArr => {
  const movieData = {}

  for (let i = 0; i < responseArr.length; i++) {
    movieData[orderOfKeys[i]] = responseArr[i]
  }

  console.log(movieData) // bingo
});
```

Here's a one liner to replace the for loop:

```
const movieData = responseArr.reduce((mD, response, index) => ({ ...mD, [orderOfKeys[index]]: response }), {})
```

Comment: I repent in dust and edit-ashes.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following, which makes a key array that will track the order of the promises and allow you to know which "user" is associated with each promise.  You can then set the movieData object correctly.

```js
const movieData = {};
// Added keyTracker array declaration here...
const promiseArr = [], keyTracker = [];
for (const user in githubAPI) {
  movieData[user] = fetch().then(res => res.json())
}
console.log(movieData);
for (const user in movieData) {
  // Track the order of the promises by saving the key in our keyTracker
  keyTracker.push(user);
  promiseArr.push(movieData[user]);
}

Promise.all(promiseArr).then(responseArr => console.log(responseArr));

// Now we have a lookup for the keys (keyTracker) that will allow us to 
// set the movieData correctly.
keyTracker.forEach((key, idx) => {
  movieData[key] = promiseArr[idx];
});
```